# Rails Error: undefined method `attribute_methods_generated?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Error:

```
undefined method `attribute_methods_generated?' for nil:NilClass
```

The code is a simple for allowing someone to register. In the controller the @tutor object is created. Whenever I remove form_for, the page loads fine, but nothing else seems to fix it.

Code:

```
<% form_for(@tutor) do |f| %>

<table class="form_table" id="home_form">
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td class="form">
            <%= f.text_field :fname, :class => 'form', :size => 30 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td class="form">
            <%= f.text_field :lname, :class => 'form', :size => 30 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td class="form">
            <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'form', :size => 30 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td class="form">
            <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'form', :size => 20 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
]
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <div align="left">
            <%= f.hidden_field :branch_id, :value => @branch.id.to_s %>
            <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'submit', :style => 'margin-left:3px;' %>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:51:in `respond_to?'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:329:in     `apply_form_for_options!'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:313:in `form_for'
app/views/tutors/register.html.erb:3:in      `_app_views_tutors_register_html_erb__142383781_2257394860_0'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
```

And here is the tutor class:

```
 class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :branch


 end
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `@tutor` is not nil in the form?  That's probably why it's doing that.  Also, you have a random `]` character in your code about 3/4ths of the way down.

Comment: What's the stacktrace for this error? I don't see how it could be occuring.

Comment: I'm sure that @tutor is not nil. Just added the stacktrace above.

Comment: What's the tutor class look like?

Comment: It's really got nothing in it. I'm totally stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had "class" as one of the rows in the table.

Thanks for the help though!